# Model structure for different categories

Tags: objective-c, model, structure

I'm creating an app where I have different categories, and these categories has got different items that I want to display in a table view. Each item has got a title, description, url, and a image. The category has got a title and all the items that belongs to that category.

Which is the best way to create models for this structure?

I was thinking about a NSObject called Category, with a NSString for the title and a NSMutableArray for the items. And then another NSObject called Item with NSStrings.

I'm going to parse a JSON with all the data. But how can I parse the JSON objects into the right category model array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model looks good enough. But why only `NSStrings` for Item. According to your description item model class should look like below:

```
@interface Item: NSObject{
    NSString *title;
    NSString *description;
    NSURL *itemURL;
    UIImage *image;
}
```

You can use `NSJSONSerialization` for parsing the json. For eg:

If you have a  json string like following you can parse it like below:

```
NSString *jsonString= @"{ \"category1\": [ { \"iTitle\" : \"item1\", \"iDescription\":\"desc1\"},{ \"iTitle\" : \"item2\", \"iDescription\":\"desc2\"}]}";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

If you want to parse and put it in classes  you can do the following :

```
for (NSString *category in jsonObj) {
    Category *categoryObj = [[Category alloc] init];
    categoryObj.title = category;
    NSArray *itemArray = [jsonObj valueForKey:category];
    for (NSDictionary *item in itemArray) {
        Item *itemObj = [[Item alloc] init];
        itemObj.title = [item valueForKey:@"title"];
        itemObj.description= [item valueForKey:@"description"];
        [categoryObj.items addObject:itemObj];
    }
}
```

To loop through a dictionary (or to access 'category1' in the string

```
@"{ \"tab1\": [{ \"category1\": [ { \"iTitle\" : \"item1\", \"iDescription\":\"desc1\"},{ \"iTitle\" : \"item2\", \"iDescription\":\"desc2\"}]}}"
```

you can use a for in loop.

```
NSDictionary *categoryDict = [[jsonObj valueForKey:"tab1"] objectAtIndex:0];
for (id key in categoryDict){
    NSLog(@"Key : %@",key);
    NSLog(@"Value: %@",[categorDict valueForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: I have another question. I've made some changes in my JSON. Now I have a "tab" aswell. Like this:

NSString *jsonString= @"{  \"tab1\": [{ \"category1\": [ { \"iTitle\" : \"item1\", \"iDescription\":\"desc1\"},{ \"iTitle\" : \"item2\", \"iDescription\":\"desc2\"}]}}]";

I can reach tab1 like you did with NSString *tab in jsonObj. But how do i reach the categoryname?

Comment: `valueForKey:` for tab would return the dictionary with first key as 'category1' . You can loop the keys of a dictionary using the for each loop. (I'll update the answer)

Comment: Gives me error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cad4f0'

Comment: I think the string is not a valid json. Try this.. @"{ \"tab1\": [{ \"category1\": [ { \"iTitle\" : \"item1\", \"iDescription\":\"desc1\"},{ \"iTitle\" : \"item2\", \"iDescription\":\"desc2\"}]}]}".  Edited the answer.

Comment: Ok cool. Thnx for all your help, really appreciate it! Now I can reach the tab name and the category name (created a tab model object with name and NSMutableArray with the categories). But how about the items in each category? How do i reach them and then push them into their category array?

Comment: You need not push them it's already there if it was in the JSON string. You can access it using the normal way of how you access array objects and dictionary values. If you want to add new. You can add on to as if you are adding to any other array. A quick look into the documentation of NSJSONSerialization will clear most of your doubts.